# How to update target table based on source table in Scala Programming

Tags: scala

I have my source S3 file and Target is My Sql -  i wanted to update target based on the source data (only matching records need to update)

i am able to get the matching date from below definition-
 val joinedDF = table_s3.join(table_MySql, table_s3("config_id") === table_MySql("config_id"),"inner")

but not sure how to udpate target table with my source - Overwrite mode is not working.

Let me know if you have this programming snippet from Scala.

Comment: Please read and follow the posting guidelines in the help documentation, as suggested when you created this account. [Minimal, Complete, Verifiable Example](https://stackoverflow.com/mcve) applies here. We cannot effectively help you until you post your MCVE code and accurately describe the problem.

Comment: Here is the snippet -    Table_S3 is my source and table_mysql is my target. I wanted to udpate table_mysql attributes   based on the id join. i am getting syntax error                                                                     
                                                                                                           
 val joinedDF = table_s3.join(table_MySql, table_s3("id") === table_MySql("id"), "inner")
                          .map(table_mysql=>(table_s3.col1,table_s3.col2 ))
                          .update(table_mysql.col1,table_mysql.col2)